# "chat.ejs" file shows before "index.ejs" file

Tags: ejs

I currently want a home page written in ejs, named "index.ejs" and a secondary chat function called "chat.ejs"

Here is the current file path

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/em904.png)

The file named "chat.ejs" displays before "index.ejs"

How would I make index.ejs display first?

Thanks!

- Colin

Comment: Is that image a screenshot from an IDE? Why is it important that chat.ejs appears first in the list?

Comment: Hello, When loading the Webpage, I need index.ejs to be the first page the user sees, however it is chat.ejs that is the first thing the user sees. I need index.ejs to display as the "home page"